# ARIMA -- Residual autocorrelation is non-significant upto lag 6 and significant beyond lag 6

Tags: sas, arima, autocorrelation

I tried to fit an AR(1) model and was examining the estimates of the model. I had a question on the output (ran in SAS - Proc ARIMA):

The residual auto-correlation up to lag 6 was non-significant (in other words - there is no auto-correlation); however, after lag 6 it is significant.

- What does that imply?
- Does that mean the model needs improvement?
- Also, why would it be significant after lag 6?

---

```
Autocorrelation Check of Residuals  (Highlighted values are the auto-correlation 
    values and significant values are italicized)
[To Lag] [Chi-Square]  [DF] [Pr > ChiSq]    [Autocorrelations]  
  6          9.46       5     0.0922     ** 0.023 0.146  0.092 -0.01   0.089  0.127**    
 12         24.68      11    *0.0101*    ** 0.17  0.178 -0.095 -0.042 -0.056 -0.103**    
 18         34.42      17    *0.0074*    ** 0.126 0.105  0.05  -0.014 -0.151 -0.005**  
 24         38.86      23    *0.0206*    **-0.046 0.042  0.133 -0.008 -0.029 -0.017**
 30         51.21      29    *0.0067*    **-0.067 0.094  0.104  0.183  0.054  0.015**
```

Comment: Would those be a series of Ljung-Box tests on the residuals, each from lag 1 up to `[To lag]`?

Answer (score 3):

The Ljung-Box statistic is not significant calculated over lags one to six lag six simply because you have no particularly large autocorrelations until lags seven & eight.  Plot & examine the auto-correlation function of the residuals. There's some evidence for lack of fit, so perhaps you can come up with a better model:  higher autocorrelations seem to repeat at intervals of seven without dropping off, suggesting seasonal differencing with a period of seven might be worth a try; possibly a seasonal moving average term.  All the same, with about 150 observations your current model doesn't look awful.

Answer (score 2):

try fitting a seasonal ARIMA, with a seasonal difference of 6.

Your model has significant autocorrellations at lags in multiples of 6.  It's just a guess on my end, but I'd think the seasonal ARIMA with difference of 6 would help.

Comment: Correlations at lags 6, 12, 18, 24, 30:
0.127, -0.103, -0.005, -0.017, & 0.015.

Correlations at lags 7, 14, 21, 28:
0.17, 0.105,  0.133, 0.183.

Which are bigger?

Comment: Oh, I see, I wasn't reading the results right. (never done arima in SAS, only R.  results look different.)

Comment: Yes, too many stars all over the place.